# Extracting data of two overlapping rasters

Tags: raster, r

I am trying extract the data of two overlapping set of rasters (one, a stack of 35 rasters, all from the same source and the second an elevation raster) to get a data.frame of the values (mean of the values) of each pixel of all the rasters.

The description of the raster stack is the following:

```r
> stack_pacifico
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 997, 709, 706873, 35  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -81.62083, -75.7125, 0.3458336, 8.654167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : F101992.v//ts.avg_vis, F101993.v//ts.avg_vis, F101994.v//ts.avg_vis, F121994.v//ts.avg_vis, F121995.v//ts.avg_vis, F121996.v//ts.avg_vis, F121997.v//ts.avg_vis, F121998.v//ts.avg_vis, F121999.v//ts.avg_vis, F141997.v//ts.avg_vis, F141998.v//ts.avg_vis, F141999.v//ts.avg_vis, F142000.v//ts.avg_vis, F142001.v//ts.avg_vis, F142002.v//ts.avg_vis, ... 
min values  :                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0, ... 
max values  :                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63, ...
```

And for the elevation raster:

```
> elevation_pacifico
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 997, 709, 706873  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -81.62083, -75.7125, 0.3458336, 8.654167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : COL_msk_alt 
values      : -16, 5164  (min, max)
```

It is my first time with raster data and I want to extract the data by grids of 1km2 (or less). I know the resolution of both rasters can be coerced to fit into that area requirement, also both dimensions are equal, so the number of pixels per raster is the same.

My question is, can I only merge all the rasters (the ones in the stack and the elevation raster) and extract the data with the confidence that all the pixels overlap (or are in the same place)? Or do I have to create a master SpatialGrid or SpatialPixel object and then extract the raster data to these objects?

---

Elevation:

```
#Download country map and filter by pacific states
colombia_departments <- getData("GADM", download=T, country="CO", level=1)
pacific_littoral <- c(11, 13, 21, 30)
pacific_littoral_map <- colombia_departments[colombia_departments@data$ID_1 %in% pacific_littoral, ]

#Download elevation data and filter it for pacific states
elevation <- getData("alt", co="COL")
elevation_pacifico <- crop(elevation, pacific_littoral_map)
elevation_pacifico <- setExtent(elevation_pacifico, rasters_extent)
```

Comment: I feel like `calc()` and `over()` may serve this purpose. Not 100% on that though, worth a shot.

Comment: Response was already made in the following SO post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685056/extracting-data-of-two-overlapping-rasters?noredirect=1#comment57120373_34685056).

Thanks for your recommendation Badger.

Comment: When you cross post like this would you mind putting the other forum in your question, just so we have knowledge of it. I don't have any issue with it, it is the fastest way to get an answer, just nice to know. Glad you got an answer!